# Push div across with a sliding animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div #navlogo containing a logo which is hidden when my navbar is static and visible when it is fixed. When the div is shown/hidden it pushes the content next to it over.

I am trying to work out how to make this content slide across with a smooth animation, rather than just being pushed.

Is it also possible to have the div containing the logo to slide in too?

Here's the script I'm using

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var nav = $('#custom-bootstrap-menu');
    var body = $('body');
    var top = 100;
    var logo = $('div#navlogo');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= top) {

        nav.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        body.addClass('padding-fifty');
        logo.css('display', 'block');

    } else {
        nav.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        body.removeClass('padding-fifty');
        logo.css('display', 'none');

    }
});
```

[Here is the JSFIDDLE im working with](https://jsfiddle.net/gx25ospo/3/) You can see how the menu content is pushed across.

If anyone can help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something **[like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gx25ospo/6/)**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you want in animation, but adding show and hide with parameter `slow` can help you get some animation like below

Fiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/rxysoxu9/

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var nav = $('#custom-bootstrap-menu');
    var body = $('body');
    var top = 100;
    var logo = $('div#navlogo');
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= top) {

        nav.addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        body.addClass('padding-fifty');
        logo.show('slow');
        //logo.css('display', 'block');

    } else {
        nav.removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        body.removeClass('padding-fifty');
        logo.hide('slow');
        //logo.css('display', 'none');

    }
});
```

```css
#logo {
    height: 100px;
}

.padding-fifty {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#navlogo {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <body>
   
<div id="logo">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>CHEEZ-IT</h1>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
<!--  something -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>   
   
   
   
   

    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <nav id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div id="navlogo">            
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CHEEZ-IT!</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Us <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Who are Cheez-it's</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Credentials</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Our Services</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Industries <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Cheeze-it Solar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cheeze-it Infrastructure</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cheeze-it Harvest</a></li>                
              </ul>
            </li>
            
            <li><a href="#contact">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>


<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">

            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>            
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND</h2>
            <h2>CONTENT IS GRAND, MAN</h2>
            
   
  </div>
 </div>
</div>



  </body>
```

Hope this helps to you!

Comment: when the div shows it slides in just like I want but when it disappears is there a way to make it slide out? Thanks